# JDK 7u10 and BlackBerry WebWorks SDK installation issues

Tags: java, web-applications, blackberry

For the past few days I have been trying to install the JDK 7u10 which is made available by Oracle. after installing this JDK, I then proceed to install BlackBerry WebWorks SDK but i keep getting he following error message: "JDK 1.6 or higher not installed" what could possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: Just a wild guess but from hearing about the BlackBerry's overall technical quality, might be the installer is just doing a simple substring match for "1.6" in currently running Java's version.

Answer (score 4):

Create enviroment variables JAVA_HOME & JAVA_PATH and point them to 32 bit version JDK bin folder.

on a cmd prompt type: set JA 
check if the variables have the right values.

javac -version and java -version should give you the good version, 32 bit!.

check if the enviroment variable PATH has not the location of 64bit path, if it has, correct it,

**On the file BlackBerryWebWorksSDK.exe don't forget to enable compatibility with Windows XP (sp3). if you are running win8 or 7**

Comment: I hhd all the variables set in enviro and still got th jdk error. When I set the compat settins it all went ok. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problems was that JDK needs to be installed as 32-bit, even in a 64-bit architecture.Try this

Answer (score 0):

Is JAVA_HOME properly set?  Are you able to run "javac" from the command line?  What version of java does "javac -version" report?